# Use string in to retrieve object

Tags: c#

Have a large object in c# which contains many strings and integers. 
for example:

```
object.something.something = "somestring";
object.something2.something = "somestring2";
```

I also have a int which represents an element in the object. for example:

```
object.something.1 = "the content of number 1";
object.something.2 = "the content of number 2";
object.something.3 = "the content of number 3";
object.something.4 = "the content of number 4";
```

and so on...

if i have a variable which contains a number such as

```
int number = 3;
```

i need to use that to find the value of `object.something.3`

Comment: Why you don't use lists or a `Dictionary<int, string>`?

Comment: Do you have any influence over the structure of the object?  If so, I suggest you rethink your design

Comment: As an alternative to dictionaries, you could also overload the square bracket operators of the class and handle both strings and integers however you need.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: Member names can't start with a number. Create a [mcve].

Comment: You can't have `object.something.1` because that is not a valid c# identifier.   Can you show some actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have the name of a method/property, which you would like to invoke. First i would think about redesigning the program, but it you don't want to, then you could use reflection

```
MethodInfo method = something.getType().GetMethod(number.ToString());
string result = (string)method.Invoke(something);
```

if it is a property then use `GetProperty(number.ToString()).GetGetMethod()` instead of `GetMethod()`